# Is Java Robot API Platform Independent

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I use selenium webdriver with Java, I used Robot API from Java for handling Window (OS) level pop-ups in automation

My Questions are,

1. is the ROBOT API platform independent, if i wanna use selenium grid
   and can the same code be executed on multiple platforms like apple,
   unix etc not just the windows ?
2. Or should i modify the code for every platform ?
3. Is Robot Framework    different from Robot API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, from the [Robot framework](http://robotframework.org/) website:

> Robot Framework is operating system and application **independent**. The
>   core framework is implemented using Python and runs also on Jython
>   (JVM) and IronPython (.NET).

2. There are [Operating-system variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variable) to help with difference between operating systems for PATHs and file endings. Which should cover the most common OS differences. Although I do not have a lot of experience with the Robot framework I expect you do not need to create custom code for each operating system.
3. No, this is the same. The package name is robot.api from [the documentation](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> robot.api package exposes the public APIs of Robot Framework.